# rails active record if statement in select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I need to use a query where I have an if condition in the select statement. Is there a way to this in rails active record?

Here is my sql involving only one table:

```
select id, voyage_id, user_id, IF(download_times > 0, "downloaded", "created") as status
from download_counts 
group by voyage_id, user_id, status
```

I found a solution by adding this function to the model:

```
  def self.with_status
    select("download_counts.*, IF(download_times > 0, \"downloaded\", \"created\") as status")
  end
```

and then calling it this way:

```
.with_status.group("voyage_id, user_id, status")
```

Is there any better solution ideally without adding that function to the model maybe?

Comment: What is your model name?

Comment: Hi the model name DownloadCount. I will update the question with my findings so far